# In what header is rsize_t defined?

Tags: c

I know the C11 standard defines `rsize_t` as `size_t` in the optional Annex K, but in what header file(s)? Where does the C standard say this type should be defined?

Comment: You should be aware that Annex K has never been implemented, by anyone.  Microsoft's compilers implement a bunch of functions with the same names but different semantics.  Yes, really.

Comment: @zwol but I thought MS came up with the idea of Annex K. How come not even they implemented them?

Comment: @DarkAtom Read [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm): "Microsoft Visual Studio implements an early version of the APIs. However, the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1. ...  As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."  Why would Microsoft do that?  The cynic in me says "vendor lock-in". Given the way Visual Studio pushes their bogus Annex K functions with false "deprecation" warnings, I'm not even sure that's cynical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**K.3.3  Common definitions `<stddef.h>`**

> 1. The header `<stddef.h>` defines a type.
> 2. The type is `rsize_t` which is
>      the type `size_t` .

Quoting the [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf).

Reading further, this is also defined in `<string.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<wchar.h>` and `<time.h>`. There may be others.

Comment: Thank you! Is it defined anywhere else? (I need to wait 6 minutes to mark your answer)

Comment: @DarkAtom Yes, see edit. I'm not claiming that's all of them, though.

Comment: In clang10, it only appears in stddef.h, but it's gated inside a bunch of #if statements that leave it out during default usage.

Comment: According to this, it is in stdint.h in C11.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error

Comment: @Juan, Annex K only says that `stdint.h` defines the macro RSIZE_MAX, unless I'm missing something

Comment: Ok, the list could go on and on. In the document you provided there are a LOT of headers that define it (stdio.h etc.)

Answer (score 1):

From https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stddef.h

`stddef.h` is a header file in the standard library of the C programming language that defines the macros NULL and offsetof as well as the types `size_t`, `wchar_t`, and `ptrdiff_t`.

rsize_t is define in `stdlib.h`